# React JS : Barcode Scanning and put that Barcode value into TextBox

Tags: reactjs, barcode, barcode-scanner, scanning

I am implementing a Barcode Scanning and put that value into Textbox.

Below is the code I have impemented.

```js
function BarcodeScanner (props) {

const [barcodeInputValue, updateBarcodeInputValue] = useState('')

function barcodeAutoFocus() {
    document.getElementById("SearchbyScanning").focus()
  }

  function onChangeBarcode(event) {
    updateBarcodeInputValue(event.target.value)
  }

  function onKeyPressBarcode(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      updateBarcodeInputValue(event.target.value)
    }
  }

return () {
            <div>
                <input
                  autoFocus={true}
                  placeholder='Start Scanning'
                  value={barcodeInputValue}
                  onChange={onChangeBarcode}
                  id='SearchbyScanning'
                  className='SearchInput'
                  onKeyDown={onKeyPressBarcode}
                  onBlur={barcodeAutoFocus}
                />
            </div>
}

}
```

So I have a question that How can I test ? Also anything I am missing in the code to implement the same apart from Barcode Scanner ?

I don't have a Barcode Scanner now. Is there anyway that I can test and implement ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just write random numbers in your input text box, then press "Enter" key. Check this:

```
function onKeyPressBarcode(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      updateBarcodeInputValue(event.target.value)
    }
  }
```

Actually, `event.keyCode === 13` means the action of pressing "Enter" key.
You don´t really need to have a Barcode Scanner, because, every Barcode Scanner send the keyCode = 13 after scanning.